# Слияние двух массивов по одинаковому значению

Tags: php, массивы, php7, foreach

Есть два масcива которые нужно объединить по одинаковому значению ключа, [SteamID64] в первой таблице и [steamid] во второй таблице.
В первом массиве [SteamID64] может быть одинаковый в примере я как раз описал этот случай.

**Первый массив**

```
$arr1 = [
    '0' => [
        "PlayerID" => "1",
        "User" => "lexa",
        "Time" => "300",
        "SteamID64" => "76561198170801830",
        "SteamID" => "STEAM_0:0:105268051"
    ],
    '1' => [
        "PlayerID" => "1",
        "User" => "lexa",
        "Time" => "250",
        "SteamID64" => "76561198170801830",
        "SteamID" => "STEAM_0:0:105268051"
    ],
    '2'=> [
        'PlayerID' => "5",
        'User' => "Player",
        "Time" => "400",
        'SteamID64' => "76561199604582870",
        'SteamI' => "STEAM_0:0:822158571"
    ],
    '3' => [
        "PlayerID" => "4",
        "User" => "idfyau",
        "Time" => "360",
        "SteamID64" => "76561198161729178",
        "SteamID" => "STEAM_0:0:100731725"
    ]
];
```

**Второй массив**

```
$arr2 = [
    '76561198170801830'=> [
      "steamid" => "76561198170801830",
      "personaname" => "Black_Mens___",
      "profileurl" => "https://steamcommunity.com/id/3523557555/",
      "avatar" => "https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/64/64d96db5c4a160205149bbfab2ccdbc7c3bad688.jpg"
    ],
    '76561198161729178'=> [
        "steamid"=> "76561198161729178",
        "personaname"=> "ак4ОнаиД",
        "profileurl"=> "https://steamcommunity.com/id/dfhfdj/",
        "avatar"=> "https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/bf/bfa372987ba46f33b75ea1078e5b0a0a001cb2d8.jpg"
    ]     
];
```

**Желаемый результат*** для игрока с [PlayerID] => 5 не было найдено пары поэтому он попадает в результат каким и был.

```
$data = [
    '0' => [
        "PlayerID" => "1",
        "User" => "lexa",
        "Time" => "300",
        "SteamID64" => "76561198170801830",
        "SteamID" => "STEAM_0:0:105268051",
        "personaname" => "Black_Mens___",
        "profileurl" => "https://steamcommunity.com/id/3523557555/",
        "avatar" => "https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/64/64d96db5c4a160205149bbfab2ccdbc7c3bad688.jpg"   
    ],
    '1' => [
        "PlayerID" => "1",
        "User" => "lexa",
        "Time" => "250",
        "SteamID64" => "76561198170801830",
        "SteamID" => "STEAM_0:0:105268051",
        "personaname" => "Black_Mens___",
        "profileurl" => "https://steamcommunity.com/id/3523557555/",
        "avatar" => "https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/64/64d96db5c4a160205149bbfab2ccdbc7c3bad688.jpg"   
    ],
    '2'=> [
        'PlayerID' => "5",
        'User' => "Player",
        "Time" => "400",
        'SteamID64' => "76561199604582870",
        'SteamI' => "STEAM_0:0:822158571"
    ],
    '3' => [
        "PlayerID" => "4",
        "User" => "idfyau",
        "Time" => "360",
        "SteamID64" => "76561198161729178",
        "SteamID" => "STEAM_0:0:100731725",
        "personaname" => "ак4ОнаиД",
        "profileurl" => "https://steamcommunity.com/id/dfhfdj/",
        "avatar" => "https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/bf/bfa372987ba46f33b75ea1078e5b0a0a001cb2d8.jpg"
    ]
];
```

Сейчас я делаю это так:

```
    foreach ($arr1 as $key => $row1) {
        foreach ($arr2 as $key => $row2) {
            if($row1['SteamID64'] == $row2['steamid'] ){
                $row1['SteamID64'] = $row2['steamid'];
                $row1['personaname'] = $row2['personaname'];
                $row1['profileurl'] = $row2['profileurl'];
                $row1['avatar'] = $row2['avatar'];
                $row1['avatarmedium'] = $row2['avatarmedium'];
                $row1['avatarfull'] = $row2['avatarfull'];
                $data[] = $row1;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

**И получаю это** Для игрока с [PlayerID] => 5 не было найдено пары и его нету в результате

```
$data = [
    '0' => [
        "PlayerID" => "1",
        "User" => "lexa",
        "Time" => "300",
        "SteamID64" => "76561198170801830",
        "SteamID" => "STEAM_0:0:105268051"
        "personaname" => "Black_Mens___"
        "profileurl" => "https://steamcommunity.com/id/3523557555/"
        "avatar" => "https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/64/64d96db5c4a160205149bbfab2ccdbc7c3bad688.jpg"   
    ],
    '1' => [
        "PlayerID" => "1",
        "User" => "lexa",
        "Time" => "250",
        "SteamID64" => "76561198170801830",
        "SteamID" => "STEAM_0:0:105268051"
        "personaname" => "Black_Mens___"
        "profileurl" => "https://steamcommunity.com/id/3523557555/"
        "avatar" => "https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/64/64d96db5c4a160205149bbfab2ccdbc7c3bad688.jpg"   
    ],
    '2' => [
        "PlayerID" => "4",
        "User" => "idfyau",
        "Time" => "360",
        "SteamID64" => "76561198161729178",
        "SteamID" => "STEAM_0:0:100731725"
        "personaname" => "ак4ОнаиД"
        "profileurl" => "https://steamcommunity.com/id/dfhfdj/"
        "avatar" => "https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/bf/bfa372987ba46f33b75ea1078e5b0a0a001cb2d8.jpg"
    ]
];
```

Проблема моего кода в том что в результат попадают только те для кого была найдена пара. Мне бы хотелось получать всех игроков у которых есть пара и у которых ее нету, как я показал в **желаемом результате***.

Comment: Не очень разбираюсь в `php` так что не смог у себя воспроизвести ваш код, но могу подкинуть идею. Сделать переменную, которая будет изначально например `false` и если `if($row1['SteamID64'] == $row2['steamid'] ){`, то менять её на `true` и после внутреннего цикла делать проверку, что если эта переменная `== false` (то есть пары не было найдено), то тут просто добавляете в результирующий массив, элемент первого массива. (то есть что-то типа этого `if(isFind == false) result[2] = array1[2]` это код не на `php`, а просто пример.

Comment: Переделайте оба массива, чтобы в качестве ключа шёл `SteamID64`. Потом объедините с помощь https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.array-merge-recursive.php

Comment: @ArchDemon такой подход не подойдет в первом массиве `SteamID64` может повторятся например четыре раза, если я сделаю как вы написали то все повторы пере запишутся в последнее вхождение.

Comment: При создании другого первого массива проверяйте на существование, если запись уже существует, делайте соответствующий обработчик. И вообще непонятно каким образом у вас может совпадать `SteamID64` у разных игроков

Comment: @ArchDemon извиняясь за непонятнки, вопрос был не совсем корректный сейчас я отредактировал вопрос. Да это так `SteamID64` уникален для каждого игрока, но в первом массиве может быть один и тот же игрок но с разным `Time`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

А если попробовать вот так?

```
foreach ($arr1 as $key => $row1) {
    $temp = $row1;
    if (array_key_exists($row1['SteamID64'], $arr2)) {
        $temp += $arr2[$row1['SteamID64']];
    }
    $data[] = $temp;

}
```

Comment: Нет к сожалению работает не так как надо.

Comment: @spl33t, что конкретно не так работает?

Comment: Ну например к `User` => `leha` присоединяется его соответствующий массив из `$arr2` + к нему же попадает из второго массива `personaname` => `ак4ОнаиД` который по `steamid` не совпадает, тоже самое случается с `User` => `idfyau`.   Но вот `User` => `Player` на месте без изменений чего я и добиваюсь. Это уже более похоже на желаемый результат.

Comment: [Скриншот выполнененого кода](https://previews.dropbox.com/p/thumb/ABC7VrcWoUC4e5edLY-iSG1edpOJyAeAk2BuRkZSc3rx8wo8IS3rEsEc-Mxpp_vqPLFC5mzTyZBaICPCWTgFQf6sUxawTTFMH1V4iOPfzyxjqtpRZQ-s5EFEBnUhhSIrMmcY-Yw1kpsIg-mJY3-5rGjD-WNpamFwUrZP28egFdfUO4u00sKdV2kVAJxRMHn52tjSkxYb8x6ViA6ykSfLJobr2n2dXarop2S-7zQEyM3lL-tAhKeRF8UviCJ04YMubHXdZwgXxjM3a1xu-FcYtmnZhw_6NaxZQg-iRlo-llfNGcXTkqalY9EGkflSs1bRdHS2nre04sdgJI7RRF2mOnbGknFtsx3JfwO_JJJZSI-LH2HMMOnntKGbNG3zY3WDFq8/p.png?fv_content=true&size_mode=5).

Comment: @spl33t, мой косяк. поправил код

Answer (score 0):

`

```
$arr1 = [
    '0' => [
        "PlayerID" => "1",
        "User" => "lexa",
        "SteamID64" => "76561198170801830",
        "SteamID" => "STEAM_0:0:105268051"
    ],
    '1' => [
        "PlayerID" => "4",
        "User"  => "idfyau",
        "SteamID64" => "76561198161729178",
        "SteamID" => "STEAM_0:0:100731725"
    ],
    '2'=> [
        'PlayerID' => "5",
        'User' => "Player",
        'SteamID64' => "76561199604582870",
        'SteamI' => "STEAM_0:0:822158571"
    ]
];


$arr2 = [
    '76561198170801830'=> [
      "steamid" => "76561198170801830",
      "personaname" => "Black_Mens___",
      "profileurl" => "https://steamcommunity.com/id/3523557555/",
      "avatar" => "https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/64/64d96db5c4a160205149bbfab2ccdbc7c3bad688.jpg"
    ],
    '76561198161729178'=> [
        "steamid"=> "76561198161729178",
        "personaname"=> "ак4ОнаиД",
        "profileurl"=> "https://steamcommunity.com/id/dfhfdj/",
        "avatar"=> "https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/bf/bfa372987ba46f33b75ea1078e5b0a0a001cb2d8.jpg"
    ]
      
];

$arr3 = [];

foreach ($arr1 as $key1 => $row1) {
    foreach($arr2 as $key2 => $row2) {
        
        if($row1['SteamID64'] == $key2) {
            $arr3[$key2] = array_merge($row1, $row2);
        }

    }
}


echo '<pre>';
print_r($arr3);
echo '</pre>';`
```

Comment: В результате выполнения вашего кода так же пропадают игроки для кого не было найдено пары + к этому он склеивает повторяющихся игроков. Сейчас я подробней описал это в самом вопросе.